# How to do a range query in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, range, document

I am currently trying to add prices for each of my Item documents in MongoDB. Many of these prices have ranges, i.e. Item A has a price range of $50-$100. How can I store such ranges in the database and then query based on these values? I was thinking of adding two attributes to each document, lowPrice and highPrice, to respectively hold the lowest of the item's price range and the highest of the item's price range. Then, when I query, I would just query for documents with lowPrice less than or equal to the query price and highPrice greater than or equal to the query price. I feel that there may be a more efficient method of doing this, however.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Your solution of having a min and max price makes good scene

Have a look at the mongo query comparisons here.

```
db.test.find({
minNum : { $gte :  50},
maxNum : { $lte :  100}
});
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/

Answer (score 4):

What if your querying range within a price(maxPrice and minPrice) and what if user not only provided maxPrice or minPrice or what if user doesn't provide any price

```
        price: { $lte: maxPrice || 1000000000, $gte: minPrice || 0 }
```

- If maxPrice is null maxPrice default value will be 100 crores
- if minPrice is null minPrice default value will be 0

This answer not pretty related to the question but someone who searching a condition like this might suit them.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.testCollection.find({
       lowVal : {$gte : 50},
       highVal : {$lte : 100}
});
```

Comment: thanks to explain your answer in order to make it valuable for the readers

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.listBySearch = (req, res) => {
    let order = req.body.order ? req.body.order : 'desc';
    let sortBy = req.body.sortBy ? req.body.sortBy : '_id';
    let limit = req.body.limit ? parseInt(req.body.limit) : 100;
    let skip = parseInt(req.body.skip);
    let findArgs = {};

    // console.log(order, sortBy, limit, skip, req.body.filters);
    // console.log("findArgs", findArgs);

    for (let key in req.body.filters) {
        if (req.body.filters[key].length > 0) {
            if (key === 'price') {
                // gte -  greater than price [0-10]
                // lte - less than
                findArgs[key] = {
                    $gte: req.body.filters[key][0],
                    $lte: req.body.filters[key][1]
                };
            } else {
                findArgs[key] = req.body.filters[key];
            }
        }
    }

    Product.find(findArgs)
        .select('-photo')
        .populate('category')
        .sort([[sortBy, order]])
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(limit)
        .exec((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: 'Products not found'
                });
            }
            res.json({
                size: data.length,
                data
            });
        });
};
```